# build(compile.link) application code with only DLL *.h header file and load DLL implementation in run-time (explicit linking)

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, dll, dynamic-linking

I have an application code which invokes a DLL lib with explicit linkage (or run time linking) for accessing an exported class.

DLL.h

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORT
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

FooDLL.h

```
#include "DLL.h"

class DLL_API Foo
{
public:
    void doSomeThing();     
};

extern "C" DLL_API Foo* _getInstance() {
   return new Foo();
}

typedef Foo* (*getInstanceFactory)();

Foo* getInstance() {
    HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA("Foo.dll");
    getInstanceFactory factory_func = (getInstanceFactory)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "_getInstance");
    return factory_func();
}
```

FooDLL.cpp

```
#include "FooDLL.h"

Foo::doSomething() {
 // .......
}
```

Application.cpp (which invokes DLL)

```
#include "FooDLL.h"

Foo* obj = getInstance();
obj->doSomething(); // XXX this line can be compiled and linked only when DLL is already in path
```

The above code can be built (e.g. compiled&linked) only when the DLL file is included in lib path. Otherwise I got *unresolved external symbol error*.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Foo::doSomething()" .....
```

Is it possible to build the application code with only DLL header file (i.e. FooDLL.h) and without DLL/LIB files during the build time? (p.s. The class implementation must be in cpp file.)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with virtual function.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void virtual doSomeThing();     
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. If you did not export a class you would not need a header file at all.
I am not sure why you placed call to LoadLibrary in the header file.
Since you are exporting class, you have to let the compiler know the type. Besides, you do not have to export entire class, you can export only specific member functions of the class you want to expose
**Your dll header** to be used in a dll and exe projects, should include following (I used my own names):

```
#ifdef WIN32DLL_EXPORTS
#define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class CWin32DLL 
{
public:
    CWin32DLL();
    int WIN32DLL_API GetInt();
};
```

**Implementation:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32DLL.h"

extern "C" WIN32DLL_API CWin32DLL* _getInstance() 
{ 
    return new CWin32DLL(); 
} 

// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see Win32DLL.h for the class definition
CWin32DLL::CWin32DLL()
{
}

int CWin32DLL::GetInt()
{
    return 42;

}
```

**Your DLL consumer:**

```
#include "Win32DLL.h"
#include "SomeOther.h"
typedef CWin32DLL* (*getInstanceFactory)();

HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibrary(_T("Win32DLL.dll")); 

getInstanceFactory factory_func = (getInstanceFactory)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "_getInstance"); 

CWin32DLL* pWin32 = factory_func();

int iRet = pWin32->GetInt();
```

Do not forget to define WIN32DLL_EXPORTS (or equivalent) in project properties, C++, Preprocessor, Preprocessor Definitions for the dll.

Comment: It seems that declaring class method without virtual keyword (even with WIN32DLL_API macro) still require DLL file for compiling/linking application code. And what I wanted is building application executable code with only DLL header files.